# How to change CSS of child element <span> inside parent <div> element Using jQuery onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two menu icons, both classed `.menuentry`, with the IDs `#topicicon` and `#searchicon`, in a menubar. Beneath them are two larger divs, `#topiclist` and `#searchform`, both initially set to `display:none;`.

What I would like to do is click each menu icon and display the corresponding larger div underneath, as well as getting rid of the other larger div if it has been display previously.

So, for example, when I click `#topicicon`, it displays `#topiclist` and hides `#searchform`.

The code is being used on this website, in the menubar at the top: http://bonfiredog.co.uk/bonfog

And this is the code that I am using.

HTML:

```
<div id="topicicon"><img src="topic_icon.png" /></div>
<div id="searchform"><img src="search_icon.png" /></div>

<div id="topiclist"></div>
<div id="searchform"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#topiclist {
     display:none;
}

#searchform {
     display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#topicicon").click(function(){
    $("#topiclist").css("display", "visible");
    $("#searchform").css("display", "none");
    }, function(){
    $("#formlist").css("display", "hidden");
});
```

Not working as of now...

Comment: use  $("#topiclist").show() to hide the div and  $("#topiclist").hide() to hide the div.

Comment: make a js fiddle for better understanding of the question & use .hide() and .show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make two **click handlers** for `#topicicon` and `#searchform` and use `.hide()` and `.show()` as shown :-

```
$("#topicicon").click(function(){
    $("#topiclist").show();
    $("#searchform1").hide();
});

$("#searchform").click(function(){
    $("#topiclist").hide();
    $("#searchform1").show();
});
```

and you are using **two div's with same id's** i.e `searchform` so change the **id** of second `searchform` div to say `searchform1` and try above code.

Comment: Thank you! As for the 'same id' issue; I mistyped; "searchform" should be "searchicon", so no need to rename IDs, apologies for mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid having to write multiple click handlers, and reuse across different components with the following:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $('.showRelated').click(function () {
    var relatedId = $(this).data('rel');
    
    $('.related').hide(); // hide all related elements
    $(relatedId).show(); // show relevant
  });
  
});
```

```css
.related {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="topicicon" class="showRelated" data-rel="#topiclist"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></div>
<div id="searchicon" class="showRelated" data-rel="#searchform"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>

<div id="topiclist" class="related">Topic List</div>
<div id="searchform" class="related">Search Form</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

"visible" is not correct value for display propriety. You should add "display: block", or "display: inline-block", or  "display: inline" or any other value that is admitted by display propriety.